# Xcode 6 iPair Air unable to run App on Device (OS version)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have a valid Provisioning profile, added iPad Air ID to Developer Account, etc..

xCode cannot identify the OS version on a new iPad Air on a new Macbook pro, I have made all updated on Latest OS.

I get this error:
Mike's iPad may be running a version of iOS that is not supported by this version of Xcode.

[image: Mike's iPad may be running a version of iOS that is not supported by this version of Xcode.]

Comment: What Xcode version have you installed? Xcode 6.1?

Answer (score 3):

I was running Xcode 6, new iPad needed Xcode 6.1 but Apple Auto-update did not download the Update.
You have to manually go to App Store and search for Xcode.

[image: Download Xcode 6.1]

Comment: my xcode version 6.1.1  and iPad iOS version 8.2 , but still get same error. Please help

Answer (score 1):

On iOS 8.1 you can only build (directly on the device, and not ad-hoc) starting from Xcode 6.1.
I am not sure why apple did this, but this is the answer.